# Return values from Remark rather than a promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, remarkjs

I have a JSON file wth a list of markdown values, I'm using Remark to parse them to HTML.
After each value is parsed I add it to an object so it's accessible, however I think I'm getting stuck somewhere in promise land because the values in the object are undefined.

```
let sections = {};

const parseMD = (val) => {
    let parse = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const file = 
            unified()
            .use(remarkParse)
            .use(remarkRehype)
            .use(rehypeStringify)
            .process(val.body);

        resolve(file);

    });

    parse.then(
        function (str) {
            sections[val.id] = str.value;
        }
    );

    return parse;
}

contents.forEach((val) => parseMD(val).then((val) => val).catch(err => console.log(err)));
```

As far as I can tell this should work... If I add a `console.log(sections)` I get `{}`, which looks like an empty object but when I expand it I see that all my content is in it:

```
section1: "blah blah blah",
section2: "something else"
...
```

But `sections[section1]` will be `undefined`.

This feels like I'm getting held up in the promise somewhere but I don't know how to fix it.

I've also tried this with `async/await` in the for loop: `content.sections.forEach(async (val) => await parseMD(val));` same results.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 2):

> If I add a `console.log(sections)` I get `{}`

This is probably because you perform this output as part of the synchronous execution, and do not wait for the promise to resolve. In short, you should only print `sections` when you are *within* a `then` callback, as that will only execute when the object has been populated.

Not your problem, but you should not create a `new Promise` when you already have one -- it doesn't bring any additional value.

Also, it is bad practice to mutate a global variable (`sections`) inside a function. Instead, let your `parseMD` be more independent, and let it just resolve to the information you need for *that* input string (the `id` and the `value`), and leave it to the user of that promise to combine those pairs of information into an object `sections`.

So do like this:

```
const parseMD = (val) => unified()
    .use(remarkParse)
    .use(remarkRehype)
    .use(rehypeStringify)
    .process(val.body)
    .then(str => [val.id, str.value]); // No access to `sections` here! Just the pair

Promise.all(contents.map(parseMD)) // Wait for ALL those little promises to resolve
    .then(Object.fromEntries) // Collect the pairs into an object
    .then(sections => { // This is the accumulated object we need
        // Do all you wish to do with sections here (not in global scope)
        console.log(sections);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
```